# Поиск в многомерном массиве PHP

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

братья!
Существует массив следующего вида :

```
Arr => [
  [0] => [
    'key' => 'value1',
    'searchstuff' => [arr('comparekey' => 'vaue'),arr(),arr(),arr()]
  ],
  [1] => [
    'key' => 'value2',
    'searchstuff' => [arr(),arr(),arr(),arr('comparekey' => 'vaue')]
  ],
  [2] => [
    'key' => 'value3',
    'searchstuff' => [arr(),arr('comparekey' => 'vaue'),arr(),arr()]
 ]
]
```

Все Arr[$i]['searchstuff'] предварительно сортируются по возрастанию. Далее мне необходимо сравнивать все три ['searchstuff'] следующим образом:

```
foreach ( $arr[0]['searchstuff'] as $one ) {
    // Calculations
    foreach ( $arr[1]['searchstuff'] as $two ) {
        // Calculations
        if (conditions) {
            break;
        }
        foreach ( $arr[2]['searchstuff'] as $three ) {
            // Calculations
            if (conditions) {
                break 2;
            } else {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Всё бы хорошо, но мне необходим доступ к `Arr[$i]['key'] => 'value'` в блоке `//Do stuff`
Кто, возможно, сталкивался с такими задачами - подскажите идеи по решению.

Спасибо!

Comment: Сестра могла бы ответить, но обиделась.

Comment: Имелось ввиду конечно же "братья по разуму\несчастью"

Comment: "Братья по разуму" -> такие же как Вы -> не знаю как решить -> вопрос лишён логики.

Comment: Согласен со всем, кроме "-> вопрос лишён логики."